# Pod security context and NFS mounting

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

According to this post:

https://netapp.io/2018/06/15/highly-secure-kubernetes-persistent-volumes/

You can't use/mount an NFS share in a pod if the pod is not having security context as privileged.

I am running a pod , with external NFS mounted but I have not specified any security context other than uid/gid. Working RW fine.

How can I check if my pod is a normal one or is privileged.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this using `kubectl get pods yourpod -o json` under `.spec.containers.securityContext` or in metadata

As an example I created 2 nginx pods: 
nginx(with privileged: true)

```
"metadata": {
    "annotations": {
        "cni.projectcalico.org/podIP": "10.48.2.3/32",
        "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Pod\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"app\":\"nginx\"},\"name\":\"nginx\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"image\":\"nginx\",\"name\":\"nginx\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":80}],\"securityContext\":{\"privileged\":true}}]}}\n",


"securityContext": {
   "privileged": true
```

and

nginx-nonprivileged

```
"metadata": {
    "annotations": {
        "cni.projectcalico.org/podIP": "10.48.2.4/32",
        "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Pod\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"app\":\"nginx\"},\"name\":\"nginx-nonprivileged\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"image\":\"nginx\",\"name\":\"nginx\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":80}]}]}}\n",
```

Comment: thats my question , that how come it can auto get privileged to true if i have not done it in my deployment at all. I will check the json too.

Comment: Nope  , security contxt has only uid and gid , nothing else

Comment: But I see the the NFS filer is monuted inside the container , how it works?